# Not able to count number of checkboxes checked using jquery code

Tags: jquery

Below is my structure.

```
<span class="mrQuestionTable">                                            
    <span id="Cell.0.0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__1" id="_Q0_C0" class="mrMultiple" value="__1"/> 
        <span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Mobile-related fraud (Fraud via mobile channels)</span>
    </span>

    <span id="Cell.0.1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__2" id="_Q0_C1" class="mrMultiple" value="__2"/>
        <span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Cost (managing, implementation related costs)</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I used the below code to count the length. Once i hit the checkbox it shows me length of 0. Instead it should show 1. Please let me know why this is happening?

```
alert($('.mrMultiple:checkbox:checked').length);
```

Comment: TRy this alert($('.mrMultiple:checked').length);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('.mrMultiple').on('change', function() {

  alert($('.mrMultiple:checked').length);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="mrQuestionTable">                                            
<span id="Cell.0.0">
<input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__1" id="_Q0_C0" class="mrMultiple"
value="__1"/>    
<span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Mobile-related fraud (Fraud via mobile 
channels)</span>
</span>
<span id="Cell.0.1">
<input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__2" id="_Q0_C1" class="mrMultiple"  
value="__2"/>
<span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Cost (managing, implementation 
related costs)</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I am checking this on click. but my code is not working. Below is my code :-       
                   $('.mrQuestionTable .mrMultiple').click(function(){    alert($('.mrMultiple:checkbox:checked').length);      }; However, code you provided is working.

Comment: You have a syntax error (missing a closing `)`) - otherwise your code would work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to check the length of the checkboxes only after a checkbox is clicked on. Otherwise the alert function will just run when the page loads and nothing is checked.

```
$(".mrMultiple").on("click", function() 
   alert($('.mrMultiple:checked').length);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am checking this on click. but my code is not working. Below is my code :-       
                   $('.mrQuestionTable .mrMultiple').click(function(){    alert($('.mrMultiple:checkbox:checked').length);      };

Comment: If it is not working you may need to wrap it in a document ready function.

Answer (score 1):

> To count number of checkbox present in the page

```
var c=$('input[type=checkbox]').length;
```

> To count number of checkboxes checked in the page

```
var cc=$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in a click function or it will only ever run once no matter how many times you click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("click", function() {
    console.log($('.mrMultiple:checkbox:checked').length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="mrQuestionTable">                                            
  <span id="Cell.0.0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__1" id="_Q0_C0" class="mrMultiple"
    value="__1"/>    
    <span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Mobile-related fraud (Fraud via mobile 
    channels)</span>
</span>
<span id="Cell.0.1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="_QC05_C__2" id="_Q0_C1" class="mrMultiple"  
    value="__2"/>
    <span class="mrMultipleText" style="">Cost (managing, implementation 
    related costs)</span>
</span>
</span>
```